# Conda install geopandas doing nothing

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, geopandas

I'm using conda with Spyder/Python 3.8.8.

I'm trying to install the geopandas package through conda-install, but when running it, I receive no output.

I've input the command `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas` and let it run for 30 minutes so far, so I doubt it's just a large package or poor connection. I don't know if I'm supposed to be seeing progress updates, but if I am, I'm not.

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What happens if you run it on the terminal or command prompt, instead of in ipython session?

Comment: It gets stuck on "solving environment", doesn't crash but just keeps spinning. Edit: got ```failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.```

Comment: Then it is just taking time...  I myself have experienced conda install long-running too.  Sometimes removing `-c conda-forge` helps, since conda-forge is large (and geopandas is also in the default channel).  In addition, geopandas particularly has a complex dependency structure.  So creating a new env via `conda create` may help.

Comment: execute this in a normal (bash, zsh) terminal, not ipython

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the base Anaconda environment, then there are packages that are conflicting with geopandas. I suggest you to create new environment for geopandas:

open anaconda command line and run this command to create new environment:

```
conda create --name gis python==3.8
```

You can use any version of python you like of course. Then you need to activate it:

```
conda activate gis
```

Now you can install geopandas and jupyter lab if you need it (Personally recommend VSCode):

```
conda install -y -c conda-forge geopandas jupyterlab

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below command to install,

```
conda install geopandas
```

or

```
pip install geopandas
```

When using pip to install GeoPandas, you need to make sure that all dependencies are installed correctly.

fiona provides binary wheels with the dependencies included for Mac and Linux, but not for Windows.

pyproj, rtree, and shapely provide binary wheels with dependencies included for Mac, Linux, and Windows.

Windows wheels for shapely, fiona, pyproj and rtree can be found at Christopher Gohlke’s website.

Depending on your platform, you might need to compile and install their C dependencies manually. We refer to the individual packages for more details on installing those. Using conda (see above) avoids the need to compile the dependencies yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This solution might not be exactly relevant, but since there is no marked solution, it might help...

I recently ran into a problem installing geopandas as well. Though I did mine through my terminal and I did receive an error message: `OSError: could not find or load spatialindex_c-64.dll`.

I used: `conda install -c conda-forge rtree=0.9.3`.

Check out this [post](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1812) for more info.